# Show and hide <div>s with jQuery event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-events

There are several advanced jQuery plugins which filter `<div>`s by corresponding id or class. This is indeed based on a simple jQuery idea, but I am not sure how to implement it. Consider a menu to show/hide the content as

```
<ul id="filters" class="menu" indicator="filter">
 <li><a href="#filter" indicator="*" class="selected">All</a></li>
 <li><a href="#filter" indicator=".first">First</a></li>
 <li><a href="#filter" indicator=".third">Third</a></li>
</ul>
```

and we want to control the display of contents:

```
<div class="box first">Something</div>
<div class="box first third">Something</div>
<div class="box third">Something</div>
```

What is the simplest jQuery Javascript code to do so?

By default, all `<div>`s are shown, when we click on a `<li>` from menu (e.g. FIRST), jQuery will filter the `<div>`s to only show `<div>`s in which the class is "first".

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you're trying to do? What does the `ul` have to do with the `div`s?

Comment: something othewise than add a click binding to the elements (with delegate in the ul) that takes the selector clicked indicator or class (if indicator doesn't exists defaults to class) and then use it as selector with jQuery .hide() or .show()?

Comment: @Purmou I just added further description to clarify the issue.

Comment: You can just use jQuery `hasClass()`: http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use attribute "indicator" as it doesn't exist. Use the class element as below. Also the A elements are not needed.

```
<ul id="filters" class="menu">
 <li class="selected all">All</li>
 <li class="first">First</li>
 <li class="third">Third</li>
</ul>
```

Then your script

```
// hide all divs 
$('div.box').css('display','hidden');

// add click handler on control list
$('ul#filters li').click(function() {

   var classList =$(this).attr('class').split(/\s+/);
    $.each( classList, function(index, item){
        if (item != 'selected') {
           $('div.'+item).css('display','block');
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `class` attribute instead of `indicator` and try the following:

```
$('#filters li').click(function(){
    $('div.' + $(this).attr('class')).show();
});
```

for this to work you would have to assign an `all` class to your first LI as well as all of your DIVs. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
  $('#filters li a').live('click', function(){
    $('.box').hide();

    indirector = $(this).attr('indicator');

    indirector = indirector.substring(1);

    if(indirector == '')
      $('.box').show();   
    else
      $('div.' + indirector).show();

  });
});
```

[Reference](http://jsbin.com/isumiy/3/edit#source)

Answer (score 1):

try this code,

```
$('#filters li').click(function(){
    $("div.box").hide();
    $('div.box' + $(this).children('a').attr('indicator')).show();
});
```